# ValueError MAC check failed when decrypting bytes in AES encrypted server client connection

Tags: python, server, client, aes

I am trying to create a secure server and client connection first by sending a RSA public key and then transfer the symmetric key encrypted from the client. Then I Give  the client the path to my file and he transfer the "rb" of the file by chunks using the BUFFER_SIZE, and it seems like it encrypts well but the server cant decrypt.

when I give the client a simple value such as b'hello'  it works perfectly but when I try to transfer the file it crashes.

```
#server side

from socket import *
import os
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

    
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

def basic_decrypt_message(nonce, key, tag, msp):
    aes_cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_EAX, nonce=nonce)
    plaintext = aes_cipher.decrypt_and_verify(msp, tag)
    return plaintext

def decrypt_message(key, msg):
    ciphertxt = msg[32:]
    tag = msg[16:32]
    nonce = msg[:16]
    return basic_decrypt_message(nonce, key, tag, ciphertxt)

addr = ('', 42080)
server_socket = socket()
server_socket.bind(addr)
server_socket.listen(5)
    
client_soc, client_addr = server_socket.accept()
print("Accepted connection from %s:%s" % client_addr)

key = RSA.generate(1024)
pubKey = key.publickey().export_key()
privKey = key.export_key()

client_soc.send(pubKey)
cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(RSA.import_key(privKey))
encrypted_symmetric_key = client_soc.recv(128)
symmetric_key = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_symmetric_key)

with open('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\file', "wb") as f:
    while True:
        bytes_read = client_soc.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print(bytes_read)
        if not bytes_read:
            break
        f.write(decrypt_message(symmetric_key,bytes_read))
```

```
#client side
from socket import *
import os
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

def encrypt_message(key, msg):
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_EAX)
    nonce = cipher.nonce
    ciphertext , tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(msg)
    return nonce + tag + ciphertext


s = socket()
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 42080))
server_pubKey = RSA.import_key(s.recv(1024))
cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(server_pubKey)
symmetric_key = get_random_bytes(16)
print(symmetric_key)
s.sendall(cipher.encrypt(symmetric_key))

file_path = "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\images.jpg"
with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
    while True:
        bytes_read = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not bytes_read:
            break
        s.sendall(encrypt_message(symmetric_key, bytes_read))
```

I have tried passing throw a simple binary value and it worked perfectly, now I get "Exception has occurred: ValueError MAC check failed" on line - plaintext = aes_cipher.decrypt_and_verify(msp, tag)

on the server side, can you help figure out what is the problem?